How to get permissions from inside a unity game so I can call the methods related to step fetching?
Im trying to create a plugin to use Google Health Connect inside of a Unity game, but Im having issues to get the user permissions.
I followed the documentation and was able to get a basic app in android studio working with permissions and step fetching, but I cant make it work as a plugin since the android class that handles all that was made as a ComponentActivity and my Plugin class is a plain class.
This is how I request the permissions on my android app:
suspend fun checkPermissionsAndRun() {
    val healthConnectClient = HealthConnectClient.getOrCreate(this)
    val PERMISSIONS =
        setOf(
            HealthPermission.getReadPermission(StepsRecord::class),
            HealthPermission.getWritePermission(StepsRecord::class)
        )
    val requestPermissionActivityContract = PermissionController.createRequestPermissionResultContract()

    val requestPermissions = registerForActivityResult(requestPermissionActivityContract) { granted ->
        if (granted.containsAll(PERMISSIONS)) {
            println("Permissions successfully granted")
        } else {
            println("Permissions not granted")
        }
    }

    val granted = healthConnectClient.permissionController.getGrantedPermissions()

    if (granted.containsAll(PERMISSIONS)) {
        println("All Permissions")
    } else {
        requestPermissions.launch(PERMISSIONS)
        println("Missing Permissions")
    }
}

Please dont mind some weird redundancy there Im a huge noob with native android stuff so I am quite lost here
My objective here is to be able to get the permissions from inside a unity game so I can call the methods related to step fetching

What exactly do you need the health permissions for? Have you checked for any documentation?
